# move data from one collection to another in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

My process is like this .

user register his `name,number,password` and submit and then in next page he select whether he is `doctor` or `user` and then transfer in next page to fill his details according to his/her choice.

**I don't know which is the best way to do that,and how do that.**

I am doing like, makes a collection `unknown` then then user has to register his details. and then if he/she select `user` from `user/doctor` then the data from collection `unknown` move to collection `user` OR similarly moves to collection `doctor`.

Please someone helps me to in solving this.

Comment: Why don't you let the user input the user/doctor field first before name/number/password so you'll know which collection to insert to, instead of inserting and then moving documents, which could be error prone?

Comment: thnx..i think you are right..